# Unable to get JNI Environment pointer?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm constantly hitting "Unable to get JNI Environment pointer!" error but cannot track down it origins. It's appearing after garbage collection (it's no different if I call GC.Collect or garbage collection occurs automatically) and then application crashes. An example log output:

```
I/monodroid-gc(15423): GC cleanup summary: 92 objects tested - resurrecting 71.
F/Mono.Android(15423): Unable to get JNI Environment pointer!
I/ActivityManager( 2679): Process LuntikAndroid9.LuntikAndroid9 (pid 15423) has
died.
```

What can cause such an error? I'm trying to reproduce it in self contained code snippet but no luck so far.

Comment: I'm not sure if SO is the best place to get help for such painstaking-monodroid stuff. I'd try IRC or the mailing list first, you can find both here: http://android.xamarin.com/Community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in the [4.0 release](http://android.xamarin.com/Releases/Mono_for_Android_4/Release_4.0.0).